# FaceTime camera has blurred lines during a FaceTime call but not during skype

Tags: ipad, facetime

When I make a video call through FaceTime on my iPad the person I talk to has blurred lines through the video. I've tested it myself by calling from my iPhone and I see these blurred lines as well. However when I make a Skype call the video is crystal clear?  It's an iPad 4 if that makes any difference. Please help me

Comment: What version of iOS is it running?

Comment: Sorry iOS version 9.1

Answer (score 1):

Try a restart, hold the power button and home button together until you see the Apple logo appear, then release. It's perfectly safe and you won't lose any data, I restart my iDevices all the time.

It that doesn't work, report the bug to Apple and hope the public release of iOS 9.2 fixes your camera. You could update to the beta of iOS 9.2 if you're desperate for the camera to work, but the beta would also cause new, bigger problems.

Comment: I've tried the soft boot and I've also factory restored my iPad but neither fixes the issue. Thanks you and I will report to apple and see if there are any solutions.

Comment: I've just updated it to iOS beta 9.2 and it seems to have fixed the issue  thank you.

Comment: @MonicaMM Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

There could be countless issues, but I'd like to mention two.

Facetime's problems may be caused due to the fact that it uses the client-server model, which is a considerably slower communication method than operating on peer-to-peer. This peer-to-peer protocol used by Skype is what makes connections more responsive, and that effectively means less bugs during video calls.

Another possibility is a bug in the app itself. The countless times I have had to do a hard reset is beyond exhaustive, but you could try and see if it helps in any way.

A hard reset is done by **pressing** and **holding down** the *power* and *home* buttons until the Apple logo appears. I wouldn't be surprised if it still doesn't work though, the app is the most faulty one I have yet used.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I took a risk and updated to iOS 9.2 beta and it seems to have solved the issue perfectly.